# Play Framework not working after updating macOS to Catalina

Tags: java-8, playframework-1.x, macos-catalina

I was using play framework in mac. After updating the macOS to Catalina. I am not able to run the command "play deps",which was working fine earlier.

I want to run play deps, to download dependencies, but seeing this error -

```
jyotimahansaria@Jyotis-MacBook-Pro ~/Documents/Bytemark/Backend_Work/play-1.3.1/myApp $ play deps
~        _            _ 
~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
~ |_|            |__/   
~
~ play! 1.3.1, https://www.playframework.com
~
Error: Could not find or load main class play.deps.DependenciesManager
```

I tried creating a simple new app and trying to run, getting below errors -

1. Run Inside play folder

```
jyotimahansaria@Jyotis-MacBook-Pro ~/Documents/Bytemark/Backend_Work/play-1.3.1 $ play run myApp
~        _            _ 
~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
~ |_|            |__/   
~
~ play! 1.3.1, https://www.playframework.com
~
~ Ctrl+C to stop
~ 
~ using java version "1.8.0_231"
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /Users/jyotimahansaria/Documents/Bytemark/Backend_Work/play-1.3.1/framework/play-1.3.1.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

2. Run inside App folder -

```
jyotimahansaria@Jyotis-MacBook-Pro ~/Documents/Bytemark/Backend_Work/play-1.3.1/myApp $ play run myApp
~        _            _ 
~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
~ |_|            |__/   
~
~ play! 1.3.1, https://www.playframework.com
~
~ Oops. conf/routes or conf/application.conf missing.
~ /Users/jyotimahansaria/Documents/Bytemark/Backend_Work/play-1.3.1/myApp/myApp does not seem to host a valid application.
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed everything related to play and setup the play again, this time in Applications instead of Documents and it's working completely fine.